# Sqlite3 not matching rows with NULL values when using inclusion operator

Tags: sqlite

For some reason, sqlite3 is not matching rows that have a NULL value for a query that clearly should match it.

Say I have an `employees` table with two columns `name` and `salary` that has the following data:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM employees;
id               name             salary
---------------  ---------------  ---------------
1                John Smith       10000
2                Mary Anderson    20000
3                David White      NULL
```

Executing the following query results in:

```
sqlite> SELECT * FROM employees WHERE salary NOT IN (10000);
id               name             salary
---------------  ---------------  ---------------
2                Mary Anderson    20000
```

Shouldn't I also expect row with id=3 to be in the list? Why isn't it on the list? I've been able to confirm this behavior in [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/28e09/3).

Comment: This seems to be acceptable behavior. NULL is not equal to anything, not even NULL. (The result of `NULL [NOT] IN (..)` is actually NULL, not TRUE/FALSE. Go tri-state SQL logic.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't compare `NULL` to anything. There are `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL` operators in SQL to deal with it.

The proper query would be

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM employees 
 WHERE salary NOT IN(50000) 
    OR salary IS NULL;
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/8c505/3)** demo